# parsing data from an api call into a text file using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

I am parsing data from an API call into a text file. However, I wanted to use async-await and break the call below call into 3 separate functions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const yargs = require("yargs");
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");

const options = yargs
  .usage("Usage: -n <name>")
  .option("n", {
    alias: "name",
    describe: "Your name",
    type: "string",
    demandOption: true,
  })
  .option("s", { alias: "search", describe: "Search Term", type: "string" })
  .argv;

const greetings = `Hello ${options.name}!`;
console.log(greetings);

console.log("Here's a random joke for you: ");
const url = options.search
  ? `https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?term${escape(options.search)}`
  : " https://icanhazdadjoke.com/";

axios.get(url, { headers: { Accept: "application/json" } }).then((res) => {
  if (options.search) {
    res.data.results.forEach((j) => {
      fs.appendFile("jokes.txt", "\n" + j.jokes, (err) => {});
    });
    if (res.data.results.length === 0) {
      console.log("no joke found ");
    }
  } else {
    fs.appendFile("jokes.txt", res.data.joke, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("File Updated");
    });
  }
});
```

So the above code works absolutely fine and generates the file perfectly, however when I tried to break it into the following below functions, I just get undefined in the text file, I am not sure why this is happening.

```
const getJoke = async (url) => {
  try {
    const joke = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
    });
    return joke;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const parseJokes = (res) => {
  if (options.search) {
    res.data.results.forEach((j) => {
      return `\n ${j.joke}`;
    });
    if (res.data.results.length === 0) {
      console.log("no joke found ");
    }
  } else {
    return res.data.joke;
  }
};

const addJokeToFile = async () => {
  const result = await getJoke(url)
    .then((res) => {
      parseJokes(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(`ERROR: ${err}`);
    });
  fs.appendFile("jokes.txt", result, (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `appendFile` from `'fs/promises'` so that you can stick with the async/await style. Since `getJoke` returns a promise I would expect `result` to be a `Promise<string | undefined>` depending on if any errors show up earlier in the chain.

```
const { appendFile } = require('fs/promises');

const addJokeToFile = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await getJoke(url);
    const parsed = parseJokes(result);
    await appendFile('jokes.txt', parsed);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: the issue now is that if one joke is returned it adds the joke perfeclty fine to the file however when multiple jokes are returned I am getting the error `The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined`

Comment: Are any of the other functions hitting a `console.log` or `console.error` branch in the conditions? That would make them return `Promise<undefined>`.

Comment: I believe that error is coming from the `appendFile`  function it seems to be recieving undefined when multiple jokes are returned

Answer (score 0):

In the second (functional approach) addJokeToFile method, you are waiting for the promise to be resolved using both ways, await and .then, following modification to the code, might help you get through:

```
const addJokeToFile = async () => {
getJoke(url)
    .then((res) => {
    // Aside, we should also return some value from parseJokes function for "no joke found " case, or return null and put a check here and only append to file when jokeString is not null.
      const jokeString = parseJokes(res);  
      fs.appendFile("jokes.txt", jokeString, (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(`ERROR: ${err}`);
    });
};
```